# React-redux error: Uncaught Type Error _store_index_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a newbie to Redux. I am trying a counter using redux but when I try to increase or decrease the counter using the increment/decrement buttons, I encounter this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _store_index_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.increment is not a function
    at increment (App.js:10:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

The state of the counter value does not change.

App.js

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import actions from './store/index.js';

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const increment = ()=> {
    dispatch(actions.increment());
  }
  const decrement = () => {
    dispatch(actions.decrement());
  }
  const addBy = () => {
    dispatch(actions.addBy(10))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter App</h1>
      <h2>{counter}</h2>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
      <button onClick={addBy}>Add By 10</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState : { counter: 0 },
    reducers: {
        increment(state, action) {
            state.counter++;
        },
        decrement(state, action) {
            state.counter--;
        },
        addBy(state, action) {
            state.counter += action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const actions = counterSlice.actions;
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: counterSlice.reducer
})

export default store;
```

What am I missing? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
import { actions } from './store/index.js';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that change got my program working.....